# React Native Redux: Error Can't find variable mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have been attempting to implement Redux into a React-Native registration app I'm working on to create a multi page form set up.

I keep getting this error:

[image]

Please review the pertaining code here under from the app's root container:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native';
import { AppRegistry,Text,View,} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import store from '../store/store';
import { Provider,connect } from  'react-redux';
import Register1 from './emailandpass'
import Register2   from './namefields'
//import login      from './login'
//import confirmation from './confirmation'
//import success      from './success'

class Loginscreen extends React.Component{
 static navigationOptions= {
  title: 'Welcome to LearnD',
        }
  render() {
   const { navigate  } = this.props.navigation;
    return(
      <Provider store={store}> 
      <View>
      <Text>Have you got an account ?</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={()=> navigate('Register1')}
        title="Register here !"
        />
      </View>
      </Provider> 

    );
  }
};

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Loginscreen},
  Register1: {screen: Register1  },
  Register2: {screen: Register2}
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Landingscreen);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You did not create a `mapStateToProps` function  yet you try to pass it to the `connect` function.
You should read the [DOCS](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) for clarity

For example:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    navigation: state.navigation 
  }
}
```

This will pass the `navigation` from `redux` `store` as a prop to your component so you can access it via `props.navigation`

Comment: that's not a valid function definition, you're missing a `return` statement and a pair of `{}` :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory.

You're trying to pass a variable named `mapStateToProps` into the `connect` function but you never defined it.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Landingscreen);
//                     ^ this isn't defined anywhere
```

You need to actually create a function that will map the state to props:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  // ...
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Landingscreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the function named *mapStateToProps* before using it:

```js
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
  const someProp = state.get('someProp');
  return {
    someProp
  }
}
```